# dynamic sql database name replace

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, replace

I have a requirement where I have to replace the database names in the dynamic sql with the new database names .

something like following:

`select * from DBName.TableName`

should become

```
select * from newDBName.TableName
```

---

`select * from [DbName].TableName`

should become

```
select * from [NewDbName].TableName
```

I have tried `string.Replace()` method but that doesn't respect all combinations a programmer can write the database names in a dynamic sql

Please help.

Comment: Could you please add a piece of code that you trued using `string.Replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to replace parts of a string, you should use a formatted string and pass in the parameter. For example:

```
var query = String.Format("select * from {0}.TableName", newDB)
```

used in a method where you can pass in the new db name and return the new query.

```
public static string GetNewQuery(string newDB) {
    return String.Format("select * from [{0}].TableName", newDB);
}
```

would result in "select * from [newDB].TableName"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx